# Determine what inspection an error belongs to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 2016.3

I am trying to find out where this inspection is so I can disable it. When I click the light bulb to disable, there is no option. I've verified that the inspection is incorrect at the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths).

```
Invalid number of arguments, expected 0..1
```

I've searched through the preferences with no success. What would be really nice is an answer on how to find inspections based on the error text they provide.

[image]

Comment: Hi, You got the answer you expected?? :))

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no such a direct automated method for that task. The best thing you can do to find out the problem is

- Go to **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Inspections**. You can find some pop-up window like below

[image]

- Based on the list of inspectios you have enabled for the current profile, you should find out what inspection/sub-inspection makes that warning. And based on the kind of warning you are getting, it would not be a hard task. For example in your case it should be because of some JavaScript/JQuery plugin. You would be able to find out based on your own list. :))

And specifically for your issue, I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206338029-Invalid-number-of-arguments-error-why-). And because you find this as a false positive, generally it can be because of your plugins are outdated or version conflicts between the libraries you are using. Hope this helps you to solve the problem. :))

Answer (score 0):

That specific inspection OP is referencing to is found in
**Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> JavaScript -> General -> Signature Mismatch**.
Where it also can be disabled or it's severity can be edited.

[image]